# Debugging MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, debugging

the story is like this, we have MySQL database called syslog, there are following tables:

```
Tables_in_syslog            |
+-----------------------------+
| plugin_camm_syslog          |
| plugin_camm_syslog_MonthDec |
| plugin_camm_syslog_MonthJan |
| plugin_camm_syslog_incoming
```

Table `plugin_camm_syslog_incoming` have storage engine MEMORY, others are `MyISAM`.

This is script running from cron every 1st day of the month:

```
<?php
# This script rotates the mysql syslog-ng database
# on a monthly basis.   Place in "/etc/cron.monthly".
# To change to weekly/daily, adjust "$date" and place
# in the appropriate cron folder.

$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "syslogadmin", "sysadmin");
if (!$link) {
    die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully\n";

// make syslog the current db
$db_selected = mysql_select_db("syslog", $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ("Can\"t use syslog : " . mysql_error());
}

// Rename the table, appending short month
$last= mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")-1, date("d"), date("Y"));
$drop= mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")-3, date("d"), date("Y"));
$d=date("M", $last); $dd=date("M", $drop);
$date="Month$d"; $dropdate="Month$dd";

// drop old table
// drop 2 month old table
$result=mysql_query("DROP TABLE `plugin_camm_syslog_$dropdate`");
//$result=mysql_query("DROP TABLE `plugin_camm_syslog_$date`");

//make new date
$last= mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")-1, date("d"), date("Y")); $d=date("M", $last);
$date="Month$d";
#echo "XX $date\n";
#die ("test $result:".mysql_error());

$result = mysql_query("ALTER TABLE `plugin_camm_syslog` RENAME `plugin_camm_syslog_$date`");
if (!$result) { die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error()); }


// Recreate the original table
$result="
    CREATE TABLE `plugin_camm_syslog` (
        `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `host` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
        `sourceip` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
        `facility` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,  
        `priority` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
        `sys_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
        `message` text,
        `status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
        `alert` smallint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`sys_date` ),
        KEY `facility` (`facility`),
        KEY `priority` (`priority`),
        KEY `sourceip` (`sourceip`),
        KEY `status` (`status`),
        KEY `alert` (`alert`),
        KEY `status_date` (`status`,`sys_date`),
        KEY `sys_date` (`sys_date`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM 
    DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
    COMMENT='camm plugin SYSLOG Data' 
    PARTITION BY RANGE ( dayofyear(sys_date)) (
        PARTITION syslog_day0 VALUES LESS THAN (0) ENGINE = MyISAM,
        PARTITION syslog_day14 VALUES LESS THAN (14) ENGINE = MyISAM,
        PARTITION syslog_day28 VALUES LESS THAN (28) ENGINE = MyISAM,
        PARTITION syslog_day42 VALUES LESS THAN (42) ENGINE = MyISAM,
        PARTITION syslog_day56 VALUES LESS THAN (56) ENGINE = MyISAM,
        PARTITION syslog_day70 VALUES LESS THAN (70) ENGINE = MyISAM, 
        PARTITION syslog_day84 VALUES LESS THAN (84) ENGINE = MyISAM, 
        PARTITION syslog_day98 VALUES LESS THAN (98) ENGINE = MyISAM, 
        PARTITION syslog_day112 VALUES LESS THAN (112) ENGINE = MyISAM, 
        PARTITION syslog_day126 VALUES LESS THAN (126) ENGINE = MyISAM, 
        PARTITION syslog_day140 VALUES LESS THAN (140) ENGINE = MyISAM, 
        PARTITION syslog_day154 VALUES LESS THAN (154) ENGINE = MyISAM, 
        PARTITION syslog_day168 VALUES LESS THAN (168) ENGINE = MyISAM, 
        PARTITION syslog_day182 VALUES LESS THAN (182) ENGINE = MyISAM, 
        PARTITION syslog_day196 VALUES LESS THAN (196) ENGINE = MyISAM, 
        PARTITION syslog_day210 VALUES LESS THAN (210) ENGINE = MyISAM, 
        PARTITION syslog_day224 VALUES LESS THAN (224) ENGINE = MyISAM, 
        PARTITION syslog_day238 VALUES LESS THAN (238) ENGINE = MyISAM, 
        PARTITION syslog_day252 VALUES LESS THAN (252) ENGINE = MyISAM, 
        PARTITION syslog_day266 VALUES LESS THAN (266) ENGINE = MyISAM, 
        PARTITION syslog_day280 VALUES LESS THAN (280) ENGINE = MyISAM, 
        PARTITION syslog_day294 VALUES LESS THAN (294) ENGINE = MyISAM, 
        PARTITION syslog_day308 VALUES LESS THAN (308) ENGINE = MyISAM, 
        PARTITION syslog_day322 VALUES LESS THAN (322) ENGINE = MyISAM, 
        PARTITION syslog_day336 VALUES LESS THAN (336) ENGINE = MyISAM, 
        PARTITION syslog_day350 VALUES LESS THAN (350) ENGINE = MyISAM, 
        PARTITION syslog_day364 VALUES LESS THAN (364) ENGINE = MyISAM, 
        PARTITION syslog_day369 VALUES LESS THAN (369) ENGINE = MyISAM
    )
";

if (mysql_query($result)) {
    echo "success in plugin-camm table creation.\n";
}
else {
    echo "no table created.\n";
}

if ( mysql_query($result)) {
    echo "success in table creation.\n";
} else {
    echo "no table created.\n";
}

mysql_close($link);


$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "cacxt", "cacxt");
if (!$link) {
    die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully\n";

$db_selected = mysql_select_db("cacti", $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ("Can\"t use cacti : " . mysql_error());
}

$result=mysql_query("TRUNCATE TABLE `plugin_camm_tree2`");
$result=mysql_query("TRUNCATE TABLE `plugin_camm_temp`");
$result=mysql_query("TRUNCATE TABLE `plugin_camm_keys`");
$result=mysql_query("UPDATE `plugin_camm_rule` SET `actual_triggered` = '0';");
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

The problem is that server is not able to handle that amounth of data anymore and around 20 day each month server is facing performance issues. I am not a MySQL ninja but trying to understand what is going on, it seems that the index filles are too big [bigger that server can handle]

See:

```
:/var/lib/mysql/syslog# ls -lh | grep G total 21G
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 2,8G 2012-12-15 00:50 plugin_camm_syslog_MonthDec#P#syslog_day350.MYD
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 1,5G 2013-01-31 14:12 plugin_camm_syslog_MonthDec#P#syslog_day350.MYI
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 1,6G 2012-12-29 00:46 plugin_camm_syslog_MonthDec#P#syslog_day364.MYD
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 2,0G 2013-01-14 00:46 plugin_camm_syslog_MonthJan#P#syslog_day14.MYD
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 1,1G 2013-01-28 08:01 plugin_camm_syslog_MonthJan#P#syslog_day14.MYI
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 2,1G 2013-01-28 05:41 plugin_camm_syslog_MonthJan#P#syslog_day28.MYD
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 1,1G 2013-01-28 08:01 plugin_camm_syslog_MonthJan#P#syslog_day28.MYI
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 1,7G 2013-02-11 00:46 plugin_camm_syslog#P#syslog_day42.MYD
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 1,7G 2013-02-21 07:29 plugin_camm_syslog#P#syslog_day56.MYD
```

Today i need to run scrip to rotate syslog, my question is that will it preserve my january / february data?

Or can someone advice what to do to reduce Index usage?

Comment: Hi! If you use the "format code" toolbar button ("{}") your source code will be correctly aligned and will even have syntax highlighting. The easier to read your question is, the more useful answers you'll get.

Answer (score 0):

Not a mysql ninja as well, but your code raised some flags for me :

- How often you use all that indexes, can you reduce the number of the
  indexes ?

  - Can sourceip, facility and priority be in a separated
    table, and store only the ids in the plugin_camm_syslog table ? (this i believe would save a lot of space)
  - What about using the suggestion from
    [How to handle large table in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899161/how-to-handle-large-table-in-mysql),
    to split your data in multiple tables, something as dailly tables for
    example

and about the logging of the operations take a look here : https://serverfault.com/questions/71071/how-to-enable-mysql-logging